# How does Apache mod_rewrite work to restrict by IP

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, restrictions

I would like to accept only certain IP(s) for a few weeks.

Only accepted IP could load this -> `www.example.com/login` not the others.

Apache 2.2 is used. The code in mod_rewrite as below :

```
RewriteMap hosts-allow txt:/conf/hosts-allow
RewriteCond "${hosts-allow:%{HTTP:X-REAL-IP}|NOT-FOUND}" "=NOT-FOUND"
RewriteRule ^/login/.* - [R]
```

I added my IP to test.

"hosts-allow" file with my IP as below

```
xxx.xxx.xxx
```

---

Another try as below :

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(m|www)\.example.com/login$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/login(.*) [PT,L]
```

None of these examples work.

---

For more information,
Before tried above examples, there was a redirect to login page to all connections on my mod_rewrite.
I tried by using as below in other `example.conf` which is called by `httpd.conf`

```
<Location "/login" >
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Location >
```

I presume that the instruction on `example.conf` is overridden by mod_rewrite

Is mod_rewrite activated at the last of all other conf files ?

Comment: Where exactly are you putting these directives? How is a request for `/login` routed?

Comment: @MrWhite The first part was added on mod_rewrite.

Comment: "The first part was added on mod_rewrite." - That doesn't make sense. I can see the code is using mod_rewrite, but _where_ exactly in your config are you putting these directives? Directly in the _server_ config? Or in a `<VirtualHost>` container (which port)? Inside a `<Directory>` section? (I assume you are not using `.htaccess` since `<Location>` blocks are not permitted in `.htaccess`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteMap hosts-allow txt:/conf/hosts-allow
> RewriteCond "${hosts-allow:%{HTTP:X-REAL-IP}|NOT-FOUND}" "=NOT-FOUND"
> RewriteRule ^/login/.* - [R]
> ```

There are a few issues here...

- The `X-REAL-IP` is unlikely to be set unless you are behind some kind of proxy server. However, `X-REAL-IP` is non-standard, so unless you specifically know this is the header to check then this is going to be empty (the rewrite-map lookup will always fail).
- Using the `R` (`redirect`) flag without specifying a *substitution* string (ie. `-`) doesn't do *anything*.
- The `L` flag is omitted so processing continues anyway.
- You've not explicitly stated the *context* in which these directives are being used (*server*, *virtualhost*, *directory* or `.htaccess`), however, the *pattern* `^/login/.*` will only match in a *server* or *virtualhost* context.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(m|www)\.example.com/login$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^/login(.*) [PT,L]
> ```

Again, there are a few issues here...

- The `HTTP_HOST` contains the requested hostname only (eg. `www.example.com`), it does not contain the URL-path. So, the above condition that attempts to match against `^(m|www)\.example.com/login$` will never be successful.

  **UPDATE:** However, do you *need* to check the requested *hostname*? Are you accepting requests to multiple hosts/domains and you need to differentiate?
- You are also missing a *substitution* string (2nd argument) in the `RewriteRule` directive. Well, `[PT,L]` will be seen as the *substitution* string which will just "break".

> ```
> <Location "/login" >
>     Order Deny,Allow
>     Deny from all
>     Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
> </Location >
> ```
>
> I presume that the instruction on example.conf is override by mod_rewrite
>
> Is mod_rewrite activated at the last of all other conf files ?

Well, mod_rewrite is actually processed *early*. And `<Location>` sections are merged *late*. Not sure why this wouldn't have worked (without seeing the rest of your config), unless mod_rewrite was triggering an external redirect?

---

Try something like the following instead using mod_rewrite. This would need to go *before* existing mod_rewrite directives.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule ^/?login - [F]
```

Where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is *your* (external) IP address.

This would serve a 403 Forbidden for any request that starts `/login` from an IP address that is *not* the one stated.

Note that this will not work if your site is behind a proxy server, since `REMOTE_ADDR` will always be the IP address of the proxy server, not the user making the request.

> **UPDATE:** What should i do if the site is behid a proxy ?

You would need to know the method by which the proxy server is passing the client IP address. You can do this by analysing the HTTP request headers that are reaching your application server (or ask the manager of the proxy server).

The defacto standard is the [`X-Forwarded-For` HTTP request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) (the standarized version is the [`Forwarded` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded) - but this is far less common currently). However, this could literally be anything, such as `X-REAL-IP` that you used in your first example.

Note that the `X-Forwarded-For` header is a comma-space separate list of the IP addresses. The client's IP address is first, followed by the IP address of each proxy server that the request passes through (if more than 1).

For example, modifying the above (mod_rewrite) example, this becomes:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule ^/?login - [F]
```

But note that you should only use this method if you *know* your server is behind a proxy - since this is easily faked otherwise.

Comment: What should i do if the site is behid a proxy ? Is there any possibility to see the value of every step ? As i have narrow knowledge in server i would be easier i could check the value of every step.

Comment: I've updated my answer with respect to being behind a proxy server. However, you should/need to know whether your server is behind a proxy server or not. "see the value of every step?" - Not sure what you mean exactly, but you can analyse all elements of the HTTP request in your server-side code/application.

Comment: What other directives do you have in your config? If the above does not work then it's quite possible you have a conflict with other directives in your config? Edit your question to include your current config, so we can take a look.